# Viewing memory address allocations

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I am running a Lenovo computer on Windows 10 Home and I would like to view what memory addresses are occupied by what programs. Preferbly, the memory addresses should start at 0x0000 or somewhere near if it can access 0x0000. And it will go all the way up to my memory limit which is 8 GB. Is there a built-in software or do I have to download something to see my memory locations. Example:

| Address | Program | 
|**0x00053 - 0x0014b** | prgA.exe

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs go in and out of memory and the same program (in and out several times) will use all different addresses. The registry changes by the second or faster.

There is nothing I have seen that will do what you want. It is, of course, easy (Task Manager) to see how much memory each program / process uses.

Here is a typical SysInternals Process Explorer view. You can see how many things are using memory. You can see some of the possible column selections. None are for actual location in memory.

[image]

Here is a decent article on memory.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-windows-10s-resource-monitor-to-track-memory-usage/

> Basically, Windows 10's memory manager creates a virtual memory system
> consisting of available physical memory and a page file system on the
> hard disk. Using this virtual memory system enables the OS to allocate
> fixed-length blocks of memory (pages) that are contiguous in both
> physical memory addressing and virtual memory addressing.

You can see that physical addressing is the computer's job. On numerous systems, memory from apps in and out of the page file will result in all different addresses.